# Export to pdf/image with Syntax highlightning - emacs

Tags: emacs, export, syntax-highlighting

I have a file open in Emacs which highlights the syntax and I want to share the file (with syntax highlighting) with another person who does not use Emacs.

Is it possible to export the file open in Emacs with syntax highlightning?

Any target format is ok: e.g. HTML, PDF, Image

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use the command `M-x htmlfontify-buffer` to create an html file with syntax highlighting from any buffer.

It's included in standard Emacs, definitely in version 24, I'm not sure about 23.

Comment: what we need to do to not generate css & javascript in output html file?

Also if I want to generate html file for selection region only?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `htmlize-buffer` that comes with 'htmlize.el' (find it at http://fly.srk.fer.hr/~hniksic/emacs/htmlize.el.cgi *(dead link?)* or install from [MELPA](http://melpa.milkbox.net/#/htmlize) or download from [the htmlize Github project](https://github.com/hniksic/emacs-htmlize). This will create a HTML file with all the syntax highlighting of your current buffer.